# Restart the for loop iteration

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am getting the **response.data[j].picture.data.url** from Facebook log in and and that I am using a append function to in a div which has id **friendslist** . Now my problem is that I want to run the for loop 1000 times and i have only 500 pictures only So how can i restart the loop from zero so that i should get only 1000 images in that div

```
 for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    $("#friendslist").append('<img src="'+response.data[j].picture.data.url+'"/>');
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the simple `modulo` math(`j%500`) here,

```
var imgAvailable = 500;

for(var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
  $("#friendslist").append('<img src="'+response.data[(j%imgAvailable)].picture.data.url+'"/>');
}
```

There is no need to restart the loop.

Comment: I appreciate your work but the total no pics will be different for other user , then what will i do . suppose I have 217 pics ya my friends has 300 . I want to run for 1000 times , for any no pics but not more than 1000

Comment: @PHP_USER1 Then just have the total number of pics in a variable and replace it in the place of 500 that i mentioned in my code..!

Comment: @rajaprabhu please now tell me the solution

Comment: @PHP_USER1 Sorry.. :( i don't know PHP... Ask that as a new question.